# HTML Agility Pack on Xamarin Descendant not working

Tags: android, xamarin, html-agility-pack

I have some HTML in this form:

```
"\r
<p>One<\/p>\r
<p>Two<\/p>"
"\r
<p>Three<\/p>\r
<p>Four<\/p>"
```

It comes like this because I'm consuming a web-service, so I cannot change the content. My problem is, when I try to fetch the `innerText` of the node, and then pass it to a TextView, it does nothing. Is there something wrong with my code? I cannot use `SelectSingleNode` as HTML Agility Pack on Xamarin doesn't allow it. Here's what I have so far:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(HTMLstring);

foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("p"))
        {
            string currentText = node.InnerText; //Fetching the InnerText of the node
            Console.WriteLine(currentText); // Testing if prints (It doesn't)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix the response by replacing `<\/p>` for `</p>`, so that HTMLAgility can parse it.

Code:

```
var HtmlBlock = @"\r
                  <p>One<\/p>\r
                  <p>Two<\/p>";
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
doc.LoadHtml(HtmlBlock.Replace(@"<\/", "</"));

foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("p"))
{
    string currentText = node.InnerText; //Fetching the InnerText of the node
    Console.WriteLine(currentText); // Testing if prints (It doesn't)
}
```